# ¿Como dejo un autocomplete siempre en frente? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el problema que la primera vez que se abre mi dialogo mi autocomplete se muestra al frente y todo bien, pero si cierro el dialogo y lo vuelvo a abrir sin recargar la pagina, el autocomplete se me queda atras del dialogo.

Este es mi codigo de autocomplete :

```
            /*Inicia Autocomplete Header Puesto*/
        $( function(){
          $("#puesto_new").autocomplete({
            source: 'auto_header_puesto.php',
            minLength:3,
            select:function(event, data){
              var id = data.item['id'];
              $("#id_header_puesto").val(id);
            }
          });
        });/*Termina Autocomplete Header Puesto*/
```

Y tengo en mi CCS esto:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2006;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

He estado probando con diferentes valor en mi z-index pero se sigue quedando atras.

Comment: Haz intentado con z-index? `css`

Comment: Puedes subir una imagen con el comportamiento y el html?

Comment: Lo uso con diferentes valores pero es el mismo resultado inicialmente lo tenia así    z-index:100000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre una respuesta a mi problema, lo que esta pasando es que si me toma el z-index que le doy en el css, pero cuando cierro mi dialogo y vuelvo a abrirlo se crea una nueva ventana y esta nueva ventana tiene prioridad sobre todo, entonces para evitarte este problema lo que hice fue poner esta linea de código justo despues de la creación de mi dialogo en jquery

```
$("#d_agregar_proceso").dialog({
});
$('.ui-dialog[aria-describedby="d_agregar_proceso"]').css('z-index','0');
```

Con esto logro que asi se cierre y abra n veces mi dialogo siempre va a ir con el z-index menor al de mi autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución elegante sería utilizar:

- [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo)

  > A que elemento debe añadirse el menú. Cuando el valor es `null`, los padres del campo de entrada serán verificados para una clase de `ui-front`. Si se encuentra un elemento con la clase `ui-front`, el menú se añadirá a ese elemento. Independientemente del valor, si no se encuentra ningún elemento, el menú se añadirá al `body`.

Ejemplo:

```
$("#puesto_new").autocomplete({
  appendTo: "#modalID", // ID del modal o body
  source: 'auto_header_puesto.php',
  minLength:3,
  select:function(event, data){
    var id = data.item['id'];
    $("#id_header_puesto").val(id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

es la respuesta a tu pregunta:

```
.ui-front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2006;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Considera explicar cómo tu código puede ayudar