# Pequeño Error en Autocomplete - JQuery - PHP - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

estoy tratando de implemetar el Autocomplete obteniendo datos de una BD, mi error es que el codigo si funiona en el input donde busco me devuelve los %likes% de parte de la BD pero en la vsita no se ve el resultado de la busqueda.
    Anexo mi codigo html y jquery ya que esta comprobado de que si me esta jalando de la BD
    :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="autocomplete/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css"/>  
        <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script src="autocomplete/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>            
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="numero_unico"> 
                                            <input type="text" id="nombre_completo"
                                                   class="form-control text-center"
                                                   placeholder="INGRESE SU NOMBRE COMPLETO" value=""> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                            <p class="notificacion"></p>
                                        </div>
```

EN JQuery sol solo es esto :

```
$(function () {
    $("#nombre_completo").autocomplete({
        source: 'php/cliente_like.php',
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

el php:

```
<?php

require '../php/conexion.php';
require '../php/clases.php';


$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];


$tra = new area();
$reg = $tra->cliente_like($searchTerm);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($reg); $i++) {

    $id = $reg[$i]["id_madre"];
    $nombre_completo = $reg[$i]["nombre_completo"];

    echo "$id|$nombre_completo\n";
}
?>
```

TAMBIEN ANEXO UNA IMAGEN :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error de `css`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya esta, lo acabo de editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el formato de la respuesta. Si revisas la opción [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) verás que los formatos que acepta son:

> - Un `array` de `strings`. Ejemplo `["Choice1", "Choice2"]`
> - Un `array` de objetos con las propiedades `label` y `value`. Ejemplo: `[{ label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

### Solución:

Una posible solución sería modificar el formato devuelto por el archivo `cliente_like.php`. Así por ejemplo:

```
<?php

require '../php/conexion.php';
require '../php/clases.php';


$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];


$tra = new area();
$reg = $tra->cliente_like($searchTerm);
$result = array(); // Arreglo con los resultados
for ($i = 0; $i < count($reg); $i++) {

    $id = $reg[$i]["id_madre"];
    $nombre_completo = $reg[$i]["nombre_completo"];

    // Agregamos al arreglo de resultados
    $result[] = array(
      'value'=> $id,
      'label'=> $nombre_completo
    );
}

// Indicamos que el formato de la respuesta es JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// Imprimimos el arreglo en formato JSON
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: ahora tengo otro problema sulcucione pero me salio otro problema y subido una nueva imagen

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53474/16597) te sirva